# Bullet spawn speed or generation speed phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

Hi all I have a function that generates bullets every time the player touches the screen.

Is there a way that I can limit the amount of bullets generated? Basically if I press the screen very quickly lots of bullets get generated but I would like to limit it to at least `i` per second instead of 2 or 3 per second.

Below you can find my firing function and my bullet creation function:

```
createBullets: function(){
    //Bullets
    this.bullets = this.add.group();
    this.bullets.enableBody = true;
    this.bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.P2JS;
    this.bullets.createMultiple(500, 'bullet', 0, false);
    this.bullets.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
    this.bullets.setAll('anchor.y', 0.5);
    this.bullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
    this.bullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);    

},

fireBullet: function(){
    this.bullet = this.bullets.getFirstExists(false);
    if (this.bullet) {
        this.bullet.reset(this.tanque.x, this.tanque.y - 20);
        this.bullet.body.velocity.y = -500;
    }
},
```

and my update function:

```
if(this.input.activePointer.isDown){
    if (!this.mouseTouchDown) {   
        this.touchDown();
    }
}else {
    if (this.mouseTouchDown) {
        this.touchUp();
    }
}
```

Any help I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had similar problems in games before. The solution I used is the same as the one posted above. I found it in this
[Phaser tutorial](https://leanpub.com/html5shootemupinanafternoon/read).

The fire function used in the tutorial is:

```
fire: function() {
if (this.nextShotAt > this.time.now) {
  return;
}

this.nextShotAt = this.time.now + this.shotDelay;
```

You can modify it to suit your purposes.

This is part of a fire function I used in a game I made:

```
    fire: function() {  
    //Make sure the player can't shoot when dead and that they are able to shoot another bullet
        if(!this.player.alive || this.time.now < this.nextFireTime) {
            return;
        }

        this.nextFireTime = this.time.now + this.fireRate;

        var bullet;
            //If weaponlvl = 0, shoot a normal bullet
            if(this.weaponlvl === 0) {
                if(this.bullet1.countDead() === 0) {
                    return; 
                }
                //Properties for the basic weapon
                this.fireRate = 500;
                bullet = this.bullet1.getFirstExists(false);
                bullet.reset(this.player.x, this.player.y-22);
                bullet.body.velocity.y = -300;
            }
```

Hope this helps you in some way.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to store two values:

1. nextShotTime: next time a shot can be fired
2. shotDelay: delay between shots (can be set like `Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2`)

I don't see where you're calling `fireBullet()` in your example code above, but either before you make the call, or within the function, you could then check to see if the `nextShotTime` is in the past. If it is, fire another bullet and then update the `nextShotTime` with the current time plus the `shotDelay`.

For example:

```
if (this.nextShotTime < this.time.now) {
    this.nextShotTime = this.time.now + this.shotDelay;
    // add your code that will fire a bullet.
}
```